# Retrieve XML metadata from a repository with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Hi everyone i try seven days now to retrive data from a repository on the web. Especially i try to retrieve a list of authors from here (which has URL:http://www.../base/author):

```
 <authors xmlns="http:www.../base" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/atom">
  <author> 
      <atom:link rel="author" type="application/xml" href="http://www.../base/author/1"/>
  </author>
  <author>
      <atom:link rel="author" type="application/xml" href="http://www.../base/author/2"/>
  </author>
  <author>
      <atom:link rel="author" type="application/xml" href="http://www.../base/author/3"/>           
  </author>
</authors>
```

And each author seperately from here:

```
<author xmlns="http://http:www.../base" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/atom">
   <name>S. Crocker</name>
   <address>None</address>
   <affiliation></affiliation>
   <email>None</email>
</author>
```

My model classes are:

```
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

   @XmlRootElement(name="author")
   public class Author {

private Long id;
private String name;
private String address;
private String affiliation;
    private String email;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setFirstName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public String getAffiliation() {
    return affiliation;
}
public void setAffiliation(String affiliation) {
    this.affiliation = affiliation;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

}
```

And:

```
  import java.util.List;

  import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

   @XmlRootElement(name="authors")
   public class AuthorList {

private List<Author> data;

public List<Author> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<Author> data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

}

The controller:

```
 public class Controller {

 protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("controller");

 private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

/**
 * Retrieves all records from the REST provider
 * and displays the records in a JSP page
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/authors", method = RequestMethod.GET)//getall
public String getAll(Model model) {


    // Prepare acceptable media type
    List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
    acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

    // Prepare header
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
    HttpEntity<Author> entity = new HttpEntity<Author>(headers);

    // Send the request as GET
    try {
        ResponseEntity<AuthorList> result = restTemplate.exchange("href="http://www.../base/author/", 
                        HttpMethod.GET, entity, AuthorList.class);
        // Add to model
        model.addAttribute("authors", result.getBody().getData());

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    // This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/personspage.jsp
    return "personspage";
}

/**
 * Retrieves a single record from the REST provider
 * and displays the result in a JSP page
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/author", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getPerson(@RequestParam("id") Long id, Model model) {


    // Prepare acceptable media type
    List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
    acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

    // Prepare header
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
    HttpEntity<Author> entity = new HttpEntity<Author>(headers);

    // Send the request as GET
    try {
        ResponseEntity<Author> result = restTemplate.exchange("href="http://www.../base/author/{id}",
                            HttpMethod.GET, entity, Author.class, id);
        // Add to model
        model.addAttribute("author", result.getBody());

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    // This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/getpage.jsp
    return "getpage";
}




}
```

And finally the one of the 2 views, the getpage:

```
  <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
  <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

  <html>
  <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>Insert title here</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Get Author</h1>

 <c:if test="${empty author}">
 No records found!
 </c:if>

 <c:if test="${!empty author}">
<table style="border: 1px solid #333">
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 100px">Id</td>
    <td>${author.id}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>${author.name}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>${author.address}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Affiliation</td>
    <td>${author.affiliation}</td>
    </tr>

            <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>${author.email}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</c:if>
```

Now, wheni just run the program i take a view which says:

No records found!

And when i give the following URL:
http://localhost:8080/Client_for_rest/author?id=1

i should receive the data from the reposiory, name email etc
but intead i receive this:
The requested resource () is not available.
I can't understand what is the problem, the mapping between the URL's
the received data?
Any propositions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first issue, it does not look like the JAXB annotations are correct, the authors xml element does not map to your AuthorList class and the inner element author within author does not map to Author class, and the namespaces are not being accounted for.

I think some quick fixes to the JAXB annotation could be:
You can define a couple of classes:
AtomLink:
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

```
public class Atomlink {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String rel;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String type;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String href;
    .......
```

an AuthorMeta, to represent the author tag within authors:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AuthorMeta {

    @XmlElement(name="link", namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/atom")
    private Atomlink link;

    public Atomlink getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(Atomlink link) {
        this.link = link;
    }
}
```

and finally the AuthorList like you already have, but with namespaces:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "authors", namespace="http:www.../base")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AuthorList {

    private List<AuthorMeta> author;

    public List<AuthorMeta> getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(List<AuthorMeta> data) {
        this.author = data;
    }
}
```

This should take care of your first issue of not being able to bind cleanly.

You will have to define the binding for the result of the author along the same lines:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "author", namespace="http://http:www.../base")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Author {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String affiliation;
    private String email;
```

Now regarding your second issue of resource not found..the mapping looks good, it may be better to set the log level to trace and see what is going on.